# Data types not reading correctly when reading text file in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, text-files

I'm reading a tab delimited text file into an array using the following code:

```
val vars = io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray.map(_.split('\11'))
```

What I end up with is `Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(a,b,c,d), Array(e,f,g,h))`

Each element in the arrays are strings, but they aren't enclosed by quotes so when I try something like `vars.indexOf(a)` I get an error because Scala doesn't know what 'a' is.  Scala seems to think a is a variable name which hasn't been defined.

Is there a way to make the elements of the arrays be enclosed in quotes as strings or is there some other way to reference the element of the array so Scala knows what it is looking for?

I'm VERY new at Scala so hopefully the solution is simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide full code snippet? *I get an error because Scala doesn't know what 'a' is.* What error precisely? `a` is either in a scope (thus defined), or not, there is nothing related to quotes in original text file

Comment: Try to move away from using `Array`s and `indexOf` ASAP as this shows an imperative way of thinking.

Comment: Can you suggest another way of reading a text file and manipulating/doing calculations with it's contents?  Arrays and indexOf are the only I could come up with.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `Array[Array[String]]`, you can map and get back an array of indexes:

```
scala> Array(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"), Array("e", "f", "g", "h"))
res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(a, b, c, d), Array(e, f, g, h))


scala> res0.indexOf("a")
res1: Int = -1

scala> res0.map(_.indexOf("a"))
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0, -1)
```

Also note that you get an error probably because you wrote `indexOf(a)` instead of `indexOf("a")`, even if what you see are letters not wrapped by double quotes, they are still strings.

You can then also know the array position using `zipWithIndex` and `filter`:

```
scala> res0.map(_.indexOf("g")).zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 != -1)
res3: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((2,1))
```

Where the first number in the tuple is the string index position and the second the array which contains the string.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf(a)` will fail in Scala for the same reason as any other language - because `a` is an undefined variable. You want `indexOf("a")`. Secondly `vars.indexOf("a")` won't work because `vars` is of type `Array[Array[String]]` and so cannot contain `"a"` - it contains `Array[String]`.

Suggest providing more code so we may be able to help more with what your trying to do.